# RESTEasy: Can @Path in resource be packaged into a list?

Tags: java, path, resteasy

I am using RESTEASY.

```
@Path("/resources")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/book")
    public String get() {...}

    @GET
    @Path("/stuff")
    public String get() {...}
}
```

Is it possible to package each @Path into a list or into an array? Maybe like this:

```
A = "/resources"
B = "/book"
C = "/stuff"
```

And resource would be this:

```
@Path("{A}")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{B}")
    public String get() {...}

    @GET
    @Path("{C}")
    public String get() {...}
}
```

So that I can just open the list and change the path without modify the value in resource.

Is it possible? If so, how to make it? Thanks for answers.

Comment: The closest thing you're going to get is to use constants. This is just how Java annotations work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like:

```
@GET
@Path("{A}")
public String getXyz(@PathParm("A") String path) {...}
```

path will contain "/resource"

see [Path Param](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/_PathParam.html)